# SQLite: Data entry interface?

Tags: user-interface, sqlite

I'd to like to use SQLite to start tracking a few things.  I won't have any trouble setting up the database itself, but I'd struggle at programming an interface.

Is there any kind of open source data entry interface to SQLite? (not just 'click-and-edit' table views').

Answer (score 3):

Look at [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). 
Contrary to it's name, it can also create and edit databases and tabless.

[image]

Comment: It looks interesting, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not just looking to be able to edit a table. I want to be able to make meaningful entries into a schema that might require updating 3-4 linked tables with each new "entry".

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice Base can [use SQLite as a backend](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_SQLite_With_OpenOffice.org), as can Kexi on Linux. (Apparently it's possible to build Kexi on Windows, but I couldn't find any free-as-in-beer Windows binaries after a cursory search.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is for a web server or not, but if you're running PHP, there is [phpLiteAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/), which is free and comparable to phpMyAdmin for mySQL.